# Time Zone value mismatch off by 1 day

Tags: javascript, timezone

I was working on an issue where the date time value wasn't getting corrected correctly. 
The problem was only present when I change my Time Zone from East Coast to West Coast. 
Now, on my localhost, I can't see the issue, however; on the QA boxes, the problem is present. 
My code is present on the QA box, but I'm quite stumped on why this issue is happening. Why is the time zone showing appropriately on my local machine, but showing the wrong date(1 day behind) on the QA Machine?

ex:  (West Coast Time Zone)

```
Input
1/6/2018 "/Date(1515225600000)/"
11/10/2018 "/Date(1515657600000)/"
10/21/2018 "/Date(1513065600000)/"

Ouput
On my machine I see the value 1/6/2018 on the QA Machine I see 1/5/2018.
On my machine I see the value 11/10/2018 on the QA Machine I see 11/9/2018.
On my machine I see the value 10/21/2018 on the QA Machine I see 10/20/2018.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
                        var dosDate = data.rows[i].DOS;
                        var convertedDosDate = Utills.DatesAndTimes.parseDateOrTodayFromServerDateTime(dosDate);
                        data.rows[i].DOS = convertedDosDate;

                        var doaDate = data.rows[i].DOA;
                        var convertedDoaDate = Utills.DatesAndTimes.parseDateOrTodayFromServerDateTime(doaDate);
                        data.rows[i].DOA = convertedDoaDate;

                    }

parseDateOrTodayFromServerDateTime: function(serverDateTime)
    {
        // TODO - replace usages with one of the other parsing methods, as appropriate; this one doesn't work in all instances

        if(serverDateTime instanceof Date)
        {
            return serverDateTime;
        }

        var parsedDate;

        try
        {
            var millisecondsRegex = /-?\d+/,
                millisecondsValue = millisecondsRegex.exec(serverDateTime),
                milliseconds = parseInt(millisecondsValue, 10);

            parsedDate = new Date(milliseconds);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            parsedDate = new Date();
        }

        return parsedDate;
    },
```

Comment: Can you also provide some concrete values you're dealing with?

Comment: Not just the output, we also need the input; i.e. a sample for `dosDate`.

Comment: updated with the inputs

Comment: Looking at the first one, `1515225600000` is `2018-01-06T08:00:00Z` which is the same as `2018-01-06T00:00:00-08:00` or `2018-01-06T03:00:00-05:00`.  All are on the same date, so I think perhaps either you're unclear about which time zone the QA machine is set to, or you may be generating the timestamps incorrectly.  Can you update your answer to also show some server-side code of how you are creating that timestamp?

Comment: It was actually a problem on the server. I just added three hours to the retrieved date since we're located in the EST.